# Cannot parse a set[AnyUrl] from .env file

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm trying to load .env config via pydantic into my fastapi app. That works for single values but not for a set (of URL's to allow for CORS in this example):

Here is the pydantic-schema:

```
from pydantic import AnyUrl
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings, SettingsConfigDict


class AppSettings(BaseSettings):
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(
        env_file=".env", env_file_encoding="utf-8"
    )
    # env_prefix = "app_"
    MODE: str = "remote"
    ENVIRONMENT: str = "dev"
    # DATABASE_URL: PostgresDsn
    IS_GOOD_ENV: bool = True
    ALLOWED_CORS_ORIGINS: set[AnyUrl]
```

and my .env file:

```
MODE=remote
ENVIRONMENT=dev
ALLOWED_CORS_ORIGINS="https://localhost","https://localhost:3000"
```

I tried with and without the quotes and even with set-brackets, but it always has error parsing that last line. Pretty sure I missed something obvious, but my search was fruitless.

As always, thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/pydantic_settings/#parsing-environment-variable-values), you should use the JSON version, which would be an array (JSON has no concept of sets):

```
ALLOWED_CORS_ORIGINS=["https://localhost","https://localhost:3000"]
```